# ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: punc (()

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I have developed an application on my local. The client and server run on different ports. The application runs fine on my local system. I have now pushed the code onto the server. When I try running the code using npm run build.

I get an error that looks like this

[image]

My urlMixin.js looks like this

```js
let path = require('path');

let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders: {}
                // other vue-loader options go here
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},

devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
},
performance: {
    hints: false
},
devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
     module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: '"production"'
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true
    })
])
}
```

Is there something wrong with my webpack? What wrong am I doing? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598037/error-in-renderer-js-from-uglifyjs-unexpected-token-punc?rq=1

Comment: Also similar: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375468/uglify-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-punc). And it looks like the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294198/1206267) probably has what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

A change from

```
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
```

to

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
[...]

  new UglifyJSPlugin()
```

with npm install --save uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
fixes it.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5858#issuecomment-338430720

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `presets` option in the js rule section of your `webpack.config`. Below is a sample snippet for js rule:

```
{
  test: /\.m?js$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }
  },
  exclude: [/node_modules/]                                                           
}
```

This error in `UglifyJs` plugin mostly happens when the file is in es6 or newer versions. I think `UglifyJs` plugin is not working on js versions newer than es5 and we need presets to add required plugins to transpile it to older versions.